# I cannot figure out why my Array list is not updating with the new values that I am stating

Tags: java, arraylist

Please let me know if I make any mistakes asking this question I understand that this is a professional forum and this is my first post.
So I am trying to finish writing a code for my APCS highschool course however I have run into a problem. Just for reference here are my instructions for the Part of the code that I am running into problems with-

3.) Create a method called updateLocation, to add the country to the city ran (Ex. London, England). Print the list.

The problem I am running into is occurring in step 3. I have written the updateLocation method and written the if loop for the method to replace the already defined locations with the Country as well, however, it is not outputting correctly.

Here is my code-

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Runner {
    private double time;
    private String atheleteName;
    private String nationality;
    private String date;
    private String location;

    public Runner(double time, String atheleteName, String nationality, String date, String location) {
        this.time = time;
        this.atheleteName = atheleteName;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.date = date;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public double getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getAtheleteName() {
        return atheleteName;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setTime(double time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setAtheleteName(String atheleteName) {
        this.atheleteName = atheleteName;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return  
        time + atheleteName + nationality + date + location;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<>();

        runners.add(new Runner(     9.58,"         Usain Bolt   ","     Jamaica   ","   16 August 2009   ","      Berlin   "));
        runners.add(new Runner(     9.69,"         Tyson Gray   ","     USA   ","       20 September 2009   ","   Shanghai   "));
        runners.add(new Runner(     9.69,"         Yohan Blake   ","    Jamaica   ","   23 August 2012   ","      Lausanne"));
        runners.add(new Runner(     9.72,"         Asafa Powell   ","   Jamaica   ","   02 September 2008   ","   Lausanne   "));
        runners.add(new Runner(     9.78,"         Nesta Carter   ","   Jamaica   ","   29 August 2010   ","      Rieti   "));
        runners.add(new Runner(     9.79,"         Maurice Greene   "," USA   ","       16 June 1999   ","        Athens   "));
        runners.add(new Runner(     9.79,"         Justin Gatlin   ","  USA   ","       05 August 2012   ","      London   "));
        runners.add(new Runner(     9.80,"          Steve Mullings   "," Jamaica   ","   04 June 2011   ","        Eugene   "));
        runners.add(new Runner( 9.84,"         Donovan Bailey   "," Canada   ","    27 July 1996   ","        Atlanta   "));
        runners.add(new Runner(9.84,"         Bruny Surin   ","    Canada   ","    22 August 1999   ","      Seville   "));
        System.out.println("\nOriginal Array- ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Time(sec):      Name:        Nationality:      Date:              Location:");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printRunners(runners);
        updateLocation(runners);
        System.out.println("\nUpdate Runners- ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Time(sec):      Name:        Nationality:      Date:              Location:");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printRunners(runners);
        insertName(runners,10.49,"   Florence (G.) Joyner   ","USA   ","       06 July 1988   ","        Indianapolis, Indiana   ");
        System.out.println("\nUpdate Runners- ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Time(sec):      Name:        Nationality:      Date:              Location:");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printRunners(runners);
        replaceName(runners,"         Bruny Surin   ","         Carl Lewis   ",   9.86   ,"     USA   ","       23 August 1991   ","      Tokyo, Japan   ");
        System.out.println("\nUpdate Runners- ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Time(sec):      Name:        Nationality:      Date:              Location:");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printRunners(runners);

    }

    public static void printRunners(ArrayList<Runner> runners){
        for(Runner runner:runners)
            System.out.println(runner);
    } 

    public static void updateLocation(ArrayList<Runner> runners){
        for(Runner runner : runners){
            if(runner.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Berlin")){
                runner.setLocation("Berlin, Germany");
            }else if(runner.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Shanghai")){
                runner.setLocation("Shanghai, China");
            }else if(runner.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("London")){
                runner.setLocation("London, England");
            }else if(runner.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Athens")){
                runner.setLocation("Athens, Greece");
            } else if(runner.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Eugene")){
                runner.setLocation("Eugene, South Africa");
            } else if(runner.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Seville")){
                runner.setLocation("Seville, France");
            }else if(runner.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Lausanne")){
                runner.setLocation("Lausanne, Spain");
            }else if(runner.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Rieti")){
                runner.setLocation("Rieti, Australia");
            }else if(runner.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Atlanta")){
                runner.setLocation("Atlanta, USA");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void insertName(ArrayList<Runner> runners, double time, String atheleteName, String nationality, String date, String location){
        Runner runner = new Runner(time,atheleteName,nationality,date,location);
        runners.add(runner);
    }

    public static void replaceName(ArrayList<Runner> runners, String searchName, String replaceName, double time, String nationality, String date, String location){
        for(Runner runner: runners){
            if(runner.getAtheleteName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchName)){
                runner.setTime(time);
                runner.setAtheleteName(replaceName);
                runner.setNationality(nationality);
                runner.setDate(date);
                runner.setLocation(location);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I expected my result to be-

### Time(sec):      Name:        Nationality:      Date:              Location:

9.58         Usain Bolt        Jamaica      16 August 2009         Berlin, Germany

9.69         Tyson Gray        USA          20 September 2009      Shanghai, China

9.69         Yohan Blake       Jamaica      23 August 2012         Lausanne, Spain

9.72         Asafa Powell      Jamaica      02 September 2008      Lausanne, Spain

9.78         Nesta Carter      Jamaica      29 August 2010         Rieti, 
Australia

9.79         Maurice Greene    USA          16 June 1999           Athens, Greece

9.79         Justin Gatlin     USA          05 August 2012         London, England

9.8          Steve Mullings    Jamaica      04 June 2011           Eugene, South Africa

9.84         Donovan Bailey    Canada       27 July 1996           Atlanta, USA

9.84         Bruny Surin       Canada       22 August 1999         Seville, France
...........................................................................
However, my output looks like this-

### Time(sec):      Name:        Nationality:      Date:              Location:

9.58         Usain Bolt        Jamaica      16 August 2009         Berlin

9.69         Tyson Gray        USA          20 September 2009      Shanghai

9.69         Yohan Blake       Jamaica      23 August 2012         Lausanne

9.72         Asafa Powell      Jamaica      02 September 2008      Lausanne

9.78         Nesta Carter      Jamaica      29 August 2010         Rieti

9.79         Maurice Greene    USA          16 June 1999           Athens

9.79         Justin Gatlin     USA          05 August 2012         London

9.8          Steve Mullings    Jamaica      04 June 2011           Eugene

9.84         Donovan Bailey    Canada       27 July 1996           Atlanta

9.84         Bruny Surin       Canada       22 August 1999         Seville

Please let me know if you have any questions about the code.

Comment: All your `if` checks in `updateLocation` method  fail because they are all padded with spaces. If you absolutely need to pad the spaces, you can use `runner.getLocation().trim()` in your `updateLocation` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings `"      Berlin   "` and `"Berlin"`  are not equal (even if you compare them ignoring the case. The first one contains the leading and trailing spaces. Remove them or replace `runner.getLocation()` with `runner.getLocation().trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `updateLocation` method to:

```
public static void updateLocation(ArrayList<Runner> runners){
    for(Runner runner : runners){
        if(runner.getLocation().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Berlin")){
            runner.setLocation("Berlin, Germany");
        }else if(runner.getLocation().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Shanghai")){
            runner.setLocation("Shanghai, China");
        }else if(runner.getLocation().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("London")){
            runner.setLocation("London, England");
        }else if(runner.getLocation().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Athens")){
            runner.setLocation("Athens, Greece");
        } else if(runner.getLocation().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Eugene")){
            runner.setLocation("Eugene, South Africa");
        } else if(runner.getLocation().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Seville")){
            runner.setLocation("Seville, France");
        }else if(runner.getLocation().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Lausanne")){
            runner.setLocation("Lausanne, Spain");
        }else if(runner.getLocation().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Rieti")){
            runner.setLocation("Rieti, Australia");
        }else if(runner.getLocation().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Atlanta")){
            runner.setLocation("Atlanta, USA");
        }
    }
}
```

The search string contains spaces whereas the `expected string` does not